# Dynamically wrap multiple instances of a component in one parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component

I'm writing a classical modal component in Vuejs made out of a wrapper, a dark overlay ( that covers the whole page behind it ) and the actual content.

The challenge is that I would like to write this

```html
<button>Trigger Modal 1</button>
<Modal :id="modal1">
    Some content
</Modal>

<button>Trigger Modal 2</button>
<Modal :id="modal2">
    More content
</Modal>
```

And get the following rendered code

```html
<button>Trigger Modal 1</button>
<button>Trigger Modal 2</button>

<div class="modal-wrapper">
   <div id="modal1">Some content</div>
   <div id="modal2">More content</div>
</div>
```

I'm doing this because I don't want to repeat any of the common elements of each modal, since there can be a lot of them on a page.

---

What I tried so far

On `beforeMount` check if this is the first `Modal` component being rendered ( by checking the DOM for `.modal-wrapper` ) and if it's in there, append the current instance there, if not add create it using `document.createElement`. But what I get is a `.modal-wrapper` element for every modal, probably because the `beforeMount` event get's fired at once for all the elements present at render time.

---

**Any ideas how I can accomplish this?**

Comment: Could you refactor the modal content into a component and reuse that instead?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I'm afraid not. Because I wan't to have each modal's content next to it's trigger, but I want all modals to leave inside a parent that's under `body`, a parent that contains all the wrappers, dark background, close buttons (etc ).